# How to specify range criterial for field in MongoDb for C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How to search document by range with MongoDB driver for C#?
usual query in mongo is something like :

```
db.collection.find({ "field" : { $gt: value1, $lt: value2 } } );
```

But how to do same with C# driver for mongoDb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var collection = Database.GetCollection<Type>("collection");
var mongoQuery = Query.GT("field", value1).LT(value2);
var list = collection.Find(mongoQuery);
```